# Aggregations according to boolean parameter inside function

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, parameters, aggregate

I have a custom function for starting a Spark job. The main goal is to group a table with multiple aggregations:

```py
.groupby(["some", "columns")
.agg(
   F.mean("col1").alias("col1_mean"),
   F.sum("col1").alias("col1_sum")                         
)
```

Now I'd like to be more flexible with the aggregations. Is there a way to in-/exclude aggregations according to a boolean value? Something like:

```py
def spark_function(mean_agg=True, sum_agg=False):
   [...]
   .groupby(["some", "columns")
   .agg(
      F.mean("col1").alias("col1_mean"), # only if mean_agg=True
      F.sum("col1").alias("col1_sum") # only if sum_agg=True                          
   )
   [...]
```

In real world, there are some aggregations that will always be done, no need to check if at least one is `True`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, but you will have to experiment on this yourself, as only you know your true needs. I'll show an example. I don't suggest putting `groupBy` into the function, as you only write it once - it's not repetitive.

Input df:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('a', 3,),
     ('a', 5,)],
    ['id', 'col1']
)
```

Example function:

```py
def spark_agg_function(cols, sum_agg=False):
    aggs = [F.mean(c).alias(f"{c}_mean") for c in cols]
    if sum_agg:
        aggs += [F.sum(c).alias(f"{c}_sum") for c in cols]
    return aggs
```

Test:

```py
df.groupBy('id').agg(
    *spark_agg_function(['col1'])
).show()
# +---+---------+
# | id|col1_mean|
# +---+---------+
# |  a|      4.0|
# +---+---------+

df.groupBy('id').agg(
    *spark_agg_function(['col1'], sum_agg=True)
).show()
# +---+---------+--------+
# | id|col1_mean|col1_sum|
# +---+---------+--------+
# |  a|      4.0|       8|
# +---+---------+--------+
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. Also for the MWE example! Upvote and accepted.